# Java : zeromq , try to set response timeout in MT server

Tags: java, timeout, zeromq

im using ZeroMQ to client / server application , 
now in my MT server i try to set timeout, i tried to set on the server :

```
socket.setReceiveTimeOut(2000);
socket.setSendTimeOut(2000);
```

with no luck , how do i set timeout on response .

this is my multi thread server code this is taken from zeromq examples for mt server :

```
/*
 *  Multithreaded Hello World server in Java
 *
 *  @author Vadim Shalts
 *  @email vshalts@gmail.com
 *
 */

import org.zeromq.ZMQ;
import org.zeromq.ZMQQueue;

class mtserver {
   static void main(String[] args) {

      final ZMQ.Context context = ZMQ.context(1);

      ZMQ.Socket clients = context.socket(ZMQ.ROUTER);
      clients.bind ("tcp://*:5555");

      ZMQ.Socket workers = context.socket(ZMQ.DEALER);
      workers.bind ("inproc://workers");

      for(int thread_nbr = 0; thread_nbr < 5; thread_nbr++) {
         Thread worker_routine = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
               ZMQ.Socket socket = context.socket(ZMQ.REP);
               socket.connect ("inproc://workers");

               while (true) {

                  //  Wait for next request from client (C string)
                  byte[] request = socket.recv (0);
                  System.out.println ("Received request: ["+new String(request,0,request.length-1)+"]");

                  //  Do some 'work'
                  try {
                     Thread.sleep (1000);
                  } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                  }

                  //  Send reply back to client (C string)
                  byte[] reply = "World ".getBytes();
                  reply[reply.length-1] = 0; //Sets the last byte of the reply to 0
                  socket.send(reply, 0);
               }
            }
         };
         worker_routine.start();
      }
      //  Connect work threads to client threads via a queue
      ZMQQueue zMQQueue = new ZMQQueue(context,clients, workers);
      zMQQueue.run();

      //  We never get here but clean up anyhow
      clients.close();
      workers.close();
      context.term();
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the timeout is in milli-seconds and not seconds?

Comment: i wish i could tell you , but i can't find any where this info ...
no java docs

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a timeout? The original examples don't use it.

Comment: the example is simple example to show simple MT server , with this .
now i need to implement timeout when the client is dead.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a timeout on the server?

A natural place to put a timeout in the client.

*socket.setReceiveTimeOut(int milliseconds);* works on a client side.